# delete button issue 'str' object is not a mapping

Tags: python, django

I have an Imageloader app that each time upload an image it will show on the html page so i added download button to the images and i want to add delete button also ,I am trying to add delete button to image each time I press the button I got error 'str' object is not a mapping, even I don't understand what this error mean I tried a lot of things but it didn't work below is my code, any help appreciated.

urls.py -main

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('image/', include('imageloader.urls'), 'imageloader'),    
]
```

urls.py -app

```
app_name = 'imageloader'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.delete_pic, name='delete_pic'),
]
```

models.py -updated

```
class Imageloader(models.Model):
def validate_file_size(value):
    filesize = value.size

    if filesize > 3000000:
        raise ValidationError(
            "The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 3MB")
    else:
        return value

image = models.ImageField(
    help_text='max size only 3mb ',
    upload_to="imageloader_file/",
    validators=[validate_file_size],
    max_length=120,
    blank=False,
    unique=True,
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.image)
```

view.py

```
def home(request):
    """this function to view the home page """
    template_home = 'index.html'
    img = Imageloader.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Imageloaderform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.cleaned_data.get("image")
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Image uploaded successfully')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Pls upload an Image!')
    else:
        form = Imageloaderform()
    return render(request, template_home, {
        'form': form,
        'img': img,
    })

def delete_pic(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        img = Imageloader.object.get(pk=pk)
        img.delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

the template:

```
{% for image2 in img %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img style="height: 300px;" class="mb-3 w-50" src="{{ image2.image.url }}" alt="images!">

            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="{{ image2.image.url }}" download>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-3">Download</button>
                </a>
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'imageloader:delete_pic' image2.id %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-2">Delete</button>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

below is the exception: -updated

```
    TypeError at /image/10/
'str' object is not a mapping
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/10/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object is not a mapping
Exception Location: D:\Work\Dummy-Website\dummy website practice\second try\practice_2 project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in resolve, line 556
Python Executable:  D:\Work\Dummy-Website\dummy website practice\second try\practice_2 project\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project',
 'D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project\\env\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project\\env\\lib',
 'D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project\\env\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\yazan bader\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\yazan bader\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project\\env',
 'D:\\Work\\Dummy-Website\\dummy website practice\\second try\\practice_2 '
 'project\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 20 Feb 2020 18:27:55 +0300
```

Comment: Can you show full exception trace?

Comment: You can not just use `self.image.delete()` you need to get the path of the image and remove it from there. Also, it is not a good idea to delete the actual file before deleting an object from database

Answer (score 0):

You can not call delete() method on the self.image as it is not an object, hence the error. In my opinion, you should use signals to do so. Once the object is deleted from the database you can remove the actual file from the file system.

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Imageloader)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes file from filesystem
    when corresponding `MediaFile` object is deleted.
    """
    if os.path.isfile(instance.image.path):
        os.remove(instance.image.path)
```

**EDIT:**

If you just want to delete the database entry then remove the code for method `delete` in you `models.py` and the `delete()` method provided by Django will work absolutely fine. Because there is no need to override the `delete` method if you are just deleting the object from the database and not performing any other action.

Comment: well thanks for help still I got this error for now I don't want to remove the file from my file system so I removed this method , will put the exception so you can see

Comment: Do you want to delete the object from the database or you want to keep the entry and just set the image to null?

Comment: yes I want to delete it from the database and I want to understand what causing this error to come up so for future will not be repeated, and removed the method from models still error occur

Comment: It should have been solved once you remove the delete method from `models.py` can you post updated code?